# Forcing WWW on Wordpress Multisite

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, multisite

We launched a multisite recently, then the client came back to us and said they absolutely needed WWW in the URL. Currently, it forces a redirect to non-WWW. So far, I have yet to be able to figure this out (which frankly, seems sad).

I've followed the standard Wordpress guide for "moving" multisite: https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress#Moving_WordPress_Multisite

I've followed WPMU Dev's guide for moving multisite to a new domain: https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/move-multisite-new-domain/

I've added the following to my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.domain.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301]
```

I've tried the following in wp-config.php:

```
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'www.domain.com');
```

and

```
define('WP_HOME','http://www.domain.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://www.domain.com');
```

I've tried both manual and blanket database search and replaces, making sure not to change anything in the GUID column.

I've tried various combinations of the above. And I still manage to run into one of two errors:

1. Database connection error, usually when I replace the database with WWW versions of the site, but use the non-WWW domain for "define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'domain.com');" in wp-config.php.
2. I get redirected too many times (presumably between the WWW and non-WWW versions of the site).

At this point it's driving me crazy and I'm hoping someone on here can possibly point me in the right direction. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's hard to guess 'cause .htaccess rules are so tricky. I'm not sure about your first problem but for second one have you tried to add `L` flag to `RewriteRule` i.e `[R=301,L]`?

Comment: @revo Hmm, tried that to no avail. Continues to redirect back and forth.

Comment: So you'd better update your question with all rewrite rules.